# Is $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]$? ($A$ noetherian and commutative)

Tags: commutative-algebra, formal-power-series, flatness, polynomial-rings

Let $A$ be a noetherian commutative ring with one and $x_1,x_2,\dots$ indeterminates.

> **Question.** Is $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]\ ?$

Recall that $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is the set of **all** formal expressions $\sum a_uu$ where $u$ runs over the set of monomials in $x_1,x_2,\dots$ and $a_u\in A$, the ring structure being the obvious one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new version of the answer. The comments refer to the previous version, which is pasted below.

The answer is Yes, that is

(a) $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]$.

Claim 1: $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Claim 2: Claim 1 implies (a).

Proof of Claim 2. Set 
$$
B_n:=A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]] \otimes_{A[x_1,\dots,x_n]}A[x_1,x_2,\dots].
$$ 
Then $B_n$ is flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. Moreover $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is the colimit of the $B_n$. As filtered colimits preserve flatness, Claim 2 is proved.

Proof of Claim 1. The ring $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ being noetherian by [Lemma 10.30.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0306) of [1], and flat over $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ by [Lemma 10.96.2(1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MB)  of [1], it is enough to verify that $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$.

But, since $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$, viewed as an $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$-module, is just a product of copies of $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$, it is flat over $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ by [Lemma 10.89.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CY) and [Proposition 10.89.6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CZ) of [1], we are done.

[1] [The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/).

An obvious variant of the above argument shows:

> If $S$ is an arbitrary set of indeterminates, then $A[[(x)_{x\in S}]]$ is flat over $A[(x)_{x\in S}]$.

---

Previous version:

The answer is Yes, that is

(a) $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]$.

Claim 1: $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Claim 2: Claim 1 implies (a).

Proof of Claim 2. Set 
$$
B_n:=A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]] \otimes_{A[x_1,\dots,x_n]}A[x_1,x_2,\dots].
$$ 
Then $B_n$ is flat over $A[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. Moreover $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is the colimit of the $B_n$. As filtered colimits preserve flatness, Claim 2 is proved.

Proof of Claim 1. The ring $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ being noetherian by [Lemma 10.30.2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0306) of [1], and flat over $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ by [Lemma 10.96.2(1)](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MB)  of [1], it is enough to verify that $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is flat over $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$.

But, since $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$, viewed as an $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$-module, is isomorphic to 
$$
(A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]])[[x_{n+1}]],
$$ 
which is flat over $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ by [Lemma 10.89.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CY) and [Proposition 10.89.6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05CZ) of [1], we are done.

[1] [The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/).

Comment: I don't understand this part: "*since $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$, viewed as an $A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$-module, is isomorphic to 
$(A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]])[[x_{n+1}]]$...*" Where are the variables from $x_{n+2}$ on?

Comment: @user26857 - As a $B$-module, $B[[t]]$ is just the product of countably many copies of $B$, and similarly for $B[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ and $B[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$. In all cases, there are only countably many monomials. Right? - Also $A[[x_1,x_2,\dots]]$ is isomorphic to $$(A[[x_1,\dots,x_n]])[[x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots]]$$ (even as a ring), but I think we agree on this.